# The computation of this probability.

Tags: probability

Imagine we have $N$ urns and $b$ balls but from that number of urns we have some of them are covered and the other ones are not. We define by $\theta$ the probability that throwing a ball it gets into an urn an obviously $\theta =0$ for the urns in the covered part.

I want to compute the probability that any urn is empty, so I've got the following formula

$$\sum_{b=0}^{\infty} \underbrace{ \sum_{j=0}^{b} \binom{b}{j} (\frac{1}{N^*})^{j}(1-\frac{1}{N^*})^{b-j} }_\text{probability that $b$ ballsgot in any urn of the uncovered ones}\; (P(b \;\text{balls fall in a uncovered urn} ))$$

Where $N^*=(\theta)(N)$. So I managed the first part as follows, pick one of the uncovered urns then the probability of that urn of being empty is in fact

$$(\frac{1}{N^*})(1-\frac{1}{N^*})^{b-1} $$

then when we want to generalize this to any urn we get a binomial distribution which result in the sum.

> Problem

I don't know how to get

$$P(b \;\text{balls fall in a uncovered urn} )$$

I think this has to be like a binomial one but I don't know with which parameters.I think it has to look like:

$$\binom{.}{b} \theta^{b} (1-\theta)^{·-b}$$

But I don't know what to include in the $\textit{dot}$-part since the total number of balls that we are throwing tends to infinity as I notice in the second sum of the probability formula.

**I did the algebra with the idea above and I've noticed that the probability that I want to compute is one so something is wrong assuming that is binomial distributed, Any help please?**

> Graphics

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47593/discussion-on-question-by-user162343-the-computation-of-this-probability).